# Recommended way to embed a text thousands of tokens long?

Tags: nlp, preprocessing, word-embeddings, embeddings

I've split the text up sections each 512 tokens long and created embeddings for each of them.

I want to combine them into 1 embedding for the full text. How do I do that? Is this even recommended?

AdaV2 has [max token limit](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/embeddings/second-generation-models) of 8k, I thought about concatenating each embedding like `str(embed1) + str(embed2) + ...` and stopping when it reaches 8k tokens. But each embed is 15k tokens if converted to a string.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to just take the embedding of the CLS token. Another way is to average all the tokens.

Key search terms are *sentence embeddings* and *document embeddings*.

The best models are specifically trained (or fine-tuned) to give good sentence embeddings. I believe InferSent and SBERT are considered current state-of-the-art?

There are also multilingual sentence-embedding models, e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.01852 (and see https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.08387 for a follow-up making them smaller).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily combine embeddings by taking the element-wise mean of them. You can do more fancy things like building attention models but this is a good way to start.

```py
import numpy as np

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [10, 20, 30]

np.mean([a, b], axis=0)

# [ 5.5, 11.,  16.5]
```